# Using BlobTrackerAuto to track people in computer vision application

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, emgucv

I am currently trying to develop a system that tracks people in a queue using EmguCV (OpenCV Wrapper). I started by running and understanting the VideoSurveilance example that's in Emgu package I downloaded. Here is my code based on the example:

```
    private static void processVideo(string fileName)
    {
        Capture capture = new Capture(fileName);
        MCvFont font = new MCvFont(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FONT.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 
            1.0, 1.0);
        BlobTrackerAuto<Bgr> tracker = new BlobTrackerAuto<Bgr>();

        //I'm using a class that I implemented for foreground segmentation
        MyForegroundExtractor fgExtractor = new MyForegroundExtractor();

        Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = vVideo.QueryFrame();
        fgExtractor.initialize(frame);

        while (frame != null)
        {
            Image<Gray, Byte> foreground = fgExtractor.getForegroundImg(frame);
            tracker.Process(frame, foreground);

            foreach (MCvBlob blob in tracker)
            {
                if (isPersonSize(blob))
                {
                    frame.Draw((Rectangle)blob, new Bgr(0, 0, 255), 3);
                    frame.Draw(blob.ID.ToString(), ref font, 
                        Point.Round(blob.Center), new Bgr(255.0, 255.0, 255.0));
                }
            }
            CvInvoke.cvShowImage("window", frame);
            CvInvoke.cvWaitKey(1);

            frame = capture.QueryFrame();
        }
    }
```

The above code is meant to process each frame of an AVI Video, and show the processed frame with red rectangles around each person in scene. I didn't like the results I was getting using the `IBGFGDetector<Bgr>` class that is used in VideoSurveilance example, so I am trying to use my own foreground detector, using Emgu's functions such as CvInvoke.cvRunningAvg(), CvInvoke.cvAbsDiff(), CvInvoke.cvThreshold() and cvErode/cvDilate(). I have a few issues:

1. The video starts with a few people already in the scene. I am not getting the blobs corresponding to the people that are in the scene when the video starts.
2. Sometimes I "lose" a person for a few frames: I had the red rectangle drawn around a person for several seconds/frames and it disappears and after a while is drawn again with a different ID.
3. As you can see from the sample code, I check if the blob may be a person checking its height and width (isPersonSize() method), and draw the red rectangle only in the ones that pass in the test. How can I remove the ones that are not person sized?
4. I want to measure the time a person stays in the scene. What's the best way to know when a blob disappeared? Should I store the IDs of the blobs that I think correspond to people in an array and at each loop check if each one is still there using `tracker.GetBlobByID()`?
5. I think I am getting better results if I don't process every frame in the loop. I added a counter variable and an if-statement to process at every 3 frames:

   ```
   if (i % 3 == 0)
       tracker.Process(frame, foreground);
   ```

I added the if-statement because the program execution was really slow. But when I did that, I was able to track people that I wasn't able before.

To summarize, I would really appreciate if someone that is more used to OpenCV/EmguCV helped me by saying if it is a good approach to track people using BlobTrackerAuto, and by helping me with the issues above. I get the feeling that I am not taking advantage of the tools EmguCV can provide me.